# Is MacOS encryption as secure if FileVault is switched on after installation?

Tags: encryption, macos, filevault

Regarding turning on MacOS' FileVault after it was not turned on for installation, it says [here](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/deployment/dep82064ec40/web)...

> If FileVault is turned on later — a process that is immediate since
> the data was already encrypted — an anti-replay mechanism prevents the
> old key (based on hardware UID only) from being used to decrypt the
> volume. The volume is then protected by a combination of the user
> password with the hardware UID as previously described.

What kind anti-replay mechanism might this be? Would the old key have been salted with a random key that is then deleted and effectively replaced with the user password?

Would setting up FileVault at installation be more secure because it doesn't require an anti-replay mechanism? It sounds to me like it's similar to a routine change of password.